# Steps to setup a new project using Visual Studio 2010 and Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I've been hardly searching info about working with VS and TFS, but after surfing a lot of webs and reading various blogs, I'm a bit confused about the steps I should follow to setup a new project. I think these below are basically the ones needed, but don't really know neither if something lefts nor the order to do them:

- Create a new Team Project Collection
- Create a new Team Project within the above collection
- Setup a server folder structure
- Create a new project in Visual Studio
- Connect the project with TFS

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are you already have a Team Project Collection (TPC) named DefaultCollection.  If not then you can only create new TPCs from the desktop of your TFS server using the TFS Administration Console.

You will need to create a new Team Project (TP) from Visual Studio 2010 (VS);  If you are using it from Windows 7 or Server 2008 R2 then make sure you run VS 'elevated.'.  This is performed by connecting to your TFS server using the Team Explorer tool in VS; then right click on the node at the top of Team Explorer and choose the option to create a new TP.  Give it a name (you can't change the name later, BTW) and choose a template in the TP creation wizard;  The Agile template seems to be the most popular.  For the rest, choose the default values.

Now you have a project and can start using TFS...

If you want to use it for source control, then one easy way to get started is to open your solution in VS while connected to your new TP, right-click on it and select the option to add it to source control.

Hopefully, that's enough to get you started!

Comment: Hi Ryan and thanks for the fast response. Imagine this scenario. I have a collection (DafaultCollection) and a team project (DefaultTeamProject) already created.
Now, I want to setup a folder structure (based on team development best practises), and then create a new visual studio project under source control.
May I setup that folder structure on the server, then perform a check-in (to mirror that in my local workspace) and then create the visual studio project adding it to source control?

Comment: Hi German! Yes.  You use the Source Control Explorer from the Team Explorer Tool to add/create the folders and then commit them to the server by checking them in.  After that you can create a new project using VS and save it in the folder structure you created in your TFS 2010 workspace on your machine.  There is an option while creating the project to add it to source control, or you can add it later using the method I described in my answer.